# javascript code fragment explanation

Tags: javascript

```
fnTest = /xyz/.test(function () {
        xyz;
    }) ? /\bparent\b/ : /.*/;
```

I can not understand how this javascript code fragment works. 
Can someone explain me, logic of this code fragment ?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsers don't always use the same `toString()` implementation for functions.  Some browsers will return the code from the function as a string, others won't.

The first part of this expression determines if the browser uses the function's code in `toString()`, because `/xyz/.test(function () { xyz; })` will give `true` only if the string `xyz` is found in the result of calling `toString()` on that function.

The rest of the expression is a ternary which will either result in `/\bparent\b/` or `/.*/`, so the entire expression can be summarized like this: "If the browser uses the function's code in `toString()`, set `fnTest` to the Regexp `/\bparent\b/`, otherwise set `fnTest` to `/.*/`.

You would use this if you were going to perform some operation with functions, but you know that you only need to do it for functions that contain a variable named `parent`.  On supported browsers you can use `fnTest.test(some_function)` to see if `some_function` contains `parent`, for browsers that can't make this determination because of the `toString()` implementation `fnTest.test(some_function)` will always return true because `/.*/` will match all strings.